# Phpo create endpoint and intercept methods

Tags: php

Hi i'm pretty new on create endpoints in php.
Now i have to create a little endpoint to intercept some updates from electronic invoice service.

From admin panel of the service i can specify endpoint url where my application is located.

For example I indicate: `www.example.com/api/endpoint/index.php`

NOte: If I set only `www.example.com/api/endpoint/`, panel admin tell me there is an error - page not found

Now in the admin panel I see I can intercept these POST methods:

```
/createInvoice

/createNotification
```

But i don't undertand HOW to differentiate there 2 methods...

Actually in my index.php i've:

```
<?php

    function call_create_invoice(
     ...
    );

    function call_create_notification(
     ...
    );

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    var_dump($_POST);
```

If I use POSTMAN to do some test using POST call, i can correctly see $_POST parameters sent.... but i don't understand how to:

- call `call_create_invoice` function if `/createInvoice` is called
- call `call_create_notification` function if `/createNotification` is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would stick to vanilla PHP, you need to parse the request URI to call the desired function like:

```php
$path = $SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch($path) {
    case('/createInvoice'):
        call_create_invoice();
        break;
    case('/createNotification'):
        call_create_notification();
        break;
}
```

As requirements grow, it may make sense to use a minimal PHP framework with routing functionality, such as [Laravel Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing).